# asp.net ajax toolkit combobox doesn't work in hidden div

Tags: asp.net, ajax, controls, toolkit

I have a combobox inside a hidden div which I use CSS display = none to make it invisible, but when I make the div visible by setting display = block, the combobox just show the input and  its button and ul list all have CSS as display = 'none', visibility ='hidden'.

I can tell it is done by combobox inbuild JavaScript because I tried to use JavaScript to set the CSS manually with no luck. It is a bug of combobox.

Below is the code to reproduce the bug.  When you run it, you can't see the dropdown:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1._Default" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>

<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
<div  id="d" style="display:none">
    <asp:ComboBox ID="ComboBox1" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem>a</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>d</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>f</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:ComboBox>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
</div>
<div ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="show();">click me</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function show() {
        var d = $get('d');
        d.style.display = 'block';
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I think it unlikely that you've found a bug in the toolkit; it is more likely that you have not understood something about the way it is supposed to be used.  Of course, it is possible that you have found a bug and that your team's trust in the toolkit is misplaced, or has a less solid basis than you'd like.  However, if you have found a bug, you need to report it to the maintainers...

Comment: it turns out it is a bug. I have to put the display logic,that show() method in js pageload not code behind, then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use "visibility=hidden" instead of "display=none" for div

Answer (score 0):

I've just had same problem and i've solved it partially. Using "hidden" instead of "none" almost worked, but strangely, the arrow icon still stays out of the div and visible, even when div was hidden.

i'm not using any style attribute applied to my hidden div, and i'm using Combobox styles without modification.

I've checked it on Chrome and IE9 by the way. Thanks for any kind of help.

Comment: i think it's about button class.

Answer (score -1):

Your button-div (ID="Button1") will postback the page as it's "runat=server". Remove that & most probably it'll work fine.

Comment: a div will not postback because of this. runat="server" only tells that the div is accessible as a HtmlControl in the server code.